# Array with a sum if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do an array that sum
 with multiple criteria with AND and OR.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQleM.png)

EXAMPLE, i cant share my real spreed sheet :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQleM.png)

what i am doing

```
=SUM(IF((B2:B6>=B8)*(B2:B6<=D8)*(OR(A2:A6="Banana";A2:A6="Banann"));C2:C6;0))
```

The general idea is:

"if TRUE and TRUE and (True or True)
then sum this column for me"

On this example is just fine but on my original spreed sheet I am just stuck because the value its just not right. Where could be my mistake??

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance!

Comment: yes hahahaha sorry I wish i could. But in the example I think it could help :P

Answer (score 1):

**SUMIFS**

You can do it using `SUMIFS`. In the diagram below I have put a criteria on each row (columns E, G and H) and a formula in column F.

**p.s.** you can use a pattern, such as `banan*` instead of `banana` (in cell E2) and it will work for both "banana" and "banann"...

[image]

The formula in `F2` is:

```
F2:
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E2,B:B,">="&G2,B:B,"<="&H2)
```

It can be copy/pasted in column F for each new criteria.